# Flask session variable doesn't persist between requests

Tags: python, flask, session-cookies

How do I save my session values between requests? I followed the guidelines here:

- https://pythonbasics.org/flask-sessions/#Session-object
- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#sessions

But the code below emits `{ 'message' : 'No session key' }` when I fetch `/` after `/quux`. In other words, the session key set in `/quux` doesn't persist.

Here's my curl commands:

```
$ curl --verbose -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/quux --cookie-jar \
cookie.txt -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "foo" : "mytest"}'
$ curl --verbose -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000 --cookie-jar \
cookie.txt -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

After, the cookie file is empty:

```
$ cat cookie.txt
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

$
```

And here's my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, session, redirect, after_this_request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
app.secret_key = 'secret'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    if "baz" in session:
        print("baz is",session['baz'])

        return jsonify({
            'message': session['baz']
        }), 200

    return jsonify({ 'message' : 'No session key' }), 400

@app.route('/quux', methods=['POST'])
def quux():
    data = request.get_json()
    session['baz'] = data["foo"]
    # it is printed out here
    for x in session:
        print("key is",x," val is",session[x])

    return redirect('/', code=302)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is completely fine.

I first tried the request in Postman and that works. If you execute the request in Postman a cookie is stored in its cookie manager containing a session id.

If you pass the cookie containing the session id to curl it also works:

```
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/quux' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Cookie: session=eyJiY...' --data '{"foo": "mytest"}'
```

Now if you use the `--cookie-jar` flag it also works without needing to pass the cookie manually:

```
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/quux' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --cookie-jar cookie-jar.txt --data '{"foo": "mytest}'
```

> -c, --cookie-jar  Write cookies to filename after operation

When testing this it helped me using curl with the `--verbose` flag. Then you can see more clearly what curl is doing.

*For people on Windows that want to try this out you need to use double quotes and escape nested double quotes with black slashes.*

Comment: Great suggestion but it doesn't work. I added `--cookie-jar cookie.txt` to both curl invocations and I get the same result. When I cat cookie.txt after it is empty. (see above)

Comment: Actually, when I pick through the HTTP convo so I can explicitly do `curl --verbose -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000 --header 'Cookie: session=eyJiYXoiOiJteXRlc3QifQ.ZCnyNA.1-IRkznCsxi4aJWx3m09Lw2x-pY' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' ` it works properly! Why doesn't it save it to disk?

Comment: And the reason is that the SECOND invocation should be `--cookie cookie.txt` not `--cookie-jar cookie.txt` ...

Comment: @Lucky Your changed post request in your question indeed doesn't work for me either. In the response I see "You should be redirected automatically...". You're missing the --location (-L) flag. Curl will follow redirects with this flag. Additionally if you still get a 'failed to save cookies...' message, be sure you're executing curl in a directory where you have file write permission.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, for curl, is to WRITE the cookie from the first request as `--cookie-jar cookie.txt` but in order to READ the cookie back in the second request, one must use the slightly different `--cookie cookie.txt` . Note the difference!

Alternatively, one can explicitly craft the cookie header as Bas van der Linden showed above: `--header 'Cookie: session=eyJiYXoiOiJteXRlc3QifQ.ZCnyNA.1-IRkznCsxi4aJWx3m09Lw2x-pY'`

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine, other items to check is when you are testing against 'localhost', make sure 'localhost' is registered as the callback address in whatever oauth2 platform you are using... 127.0.0.1, ie 127.0.0.1 != localhost from oauth perspective, even if is is from a domain perspective.

I got caught on this one wondering why all my old code that worked didn't all of a sudden, and the issue was actually PEBCAK ;)